# Is there a format to use in json to communicate with a REST server?

Tags: json, rest

One of my first interactions with json is when I did a RPC project where i found in wikipedia that a common format to use is like this one (client to server):

```
{
    "method": "methodAddUser",
    "params": 
    {
        "idUser": "Usuario1",
        "name": "Luisito Comunica",
        "password": "123",
        "email": "luisito@",
        "cel": "642000000"
    }
}
```

But for a REST project, is it recommended that I keep using that kind of format, or what format do you recommend?

Comment: you should talk to the backends, api developers, maybe there is fixed format, front end is supposed to follow API format, not rule it

Comment: Are you going to consume existing REST API or going to design a one? If you are going to consume an existing one you should find the API documentation and follow it. But if you are trying to design a REST API it prefers CRUD operations with HTTP methods (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) try going through https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/ for better idea.

Comment: Thanks, i am designing one for a school project, but i did not know if i needed to follow any standarized format, so i believe the best i sent the information without things like "params" and "method".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using a RPC service, but if I would use a REST server i probably would use the same format as above but without the "method" part since is not necessary for REST.